# Finding a concrete dual base for $B = (1-x,x,x^2-x)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I did manage to compute the dual space for the isomorphism of $B$ to $F^3$

I got the three following functionals:

$l_1 = \left [ 1\;0\;0 \right ]$

$l_2 = \left [ 1\;1\;1 \right ]$

$l_3 = \left [ 0\;0\;1 \right ]$

Is there a way to conclude anything from that?

Comment: What do you mean by isomorphism really? On the level of vector spaces, it's just a choice of basis. However, when you consider dual basis, you need to specify inner product you are working with.

Comment: @Ennar I represented the vectors in B as their coordinates vector in relation to $(1,x,x^2)$

Comment: @Ennar I have yet to study inner products

Comment: Nevermind me, I was thinking of something else entirely. Your work looks correct to me. However, what would you like to know? You wrote these functionals in standard basis, so it tells you how they act on canonical basis $(1,x,x^2)$. Expanding by linearity can give you a general formula what these functionals are as actual functions.

Comment: @Ennar Could you please show what do you mean by expanding by linearity? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, your work looks correct to me. What you've done is write these functionals in standard basis. That tells you how these functionals act on $1,x, x^2$. So, you can expand it by linearity, for example:

$$l_2(a+bx+cx^2) = a\, l_2(1) + b\, l_2(x) + c\, l_2(x^2) = a + b + c.$$

This tells you what $l_2$ is as a function $\mathcal P_2\to \mathbb F$ (where $\mathcal P_2$ is the vector space of polynomials in $\mathbb F[x]$ of degree less or equal than $2$ ).

Try doing others yourself.

Comment: Why does $l_2(1), \; l_2(x), \; l_2(x^2)$ = 1?

Comment: @vpam, because you wrote it: $l_2 = [1\ 1\ 1] = [l_2(1)\ l_2(x)\ l_2(x^2)].$

Comment: So $a,b,c$ are just the coefficients of $B$ in relation to the standard basis?

Comment: @vpam, no, $a,b,c$ are coefficients used to represent general polynomial of degree $2$ or less in standard basis.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need took about inner products for this. If we have a finite-dimensional vector space $\textsf V$, and $\beta = \{ v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n \}$ a basis for it, the *dual basis* of $\beta$, let say $\beta^* = \{ f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n \}$, is the basis for the dual space $\textsf V^*$ such that
$$f_i(v_j) = \delta_{ij}$$
So, your "functionals $l_1$, $l_2$ and $l_3$" doesn't really make any sense.

In your concrete example, since any polinomial $a+bx+cx^2$ can be written as
$$a(1-x)+(a+b+c)x+c(x^2-x)$$
then, the dual basis for $B$ are the set of functionals $B^*=\{g_1,g_2,g_3\}$ defined by
$$g_1(a+bx+cx^2)=a$$
$$g_2(a+bx+cx^2)=a+b+c$$
$$g_3(a+bx+cx^2)=c$$

Comment: If you write your functionals in matrix form wrt canonical basis, you will get the same thing as OP.

Comment: I see. Now I understand their point.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the word "concrete" means "easily interpretable. Let us call

$$f_1(x)=1-x, f_2(x)=x, f_3(x)=x^2-x$$

Let us call $ev_a$ the evaluation form, meaning that $ev_a$ is defined, for any polynomial $p$ (here with degree $\leq 2$), by :

$$ev_a(p):=p(a)$$

Clearly, any $ev_a$ belongs to the dual space (it is a linear form : $ev_a(k_1p_1+k_2p_2)=k_1 ev_a(p_1)+k_2ev_a(p_2)$ for any $k_1,p_1,k_2,p_2$)

Let us try $ev_0$ and $ev_1$. What do we find ?

$$ev_0(p_1)=1, \ \ ev_0(p_2)=0,  \ \ ev_0(p_3)=0 \ \ \ \text{and}$$

$$ev_1(p_1)=0, \ \ ev_1(p_2)=1,  \ \ ev_1(p_3)=0$$

Good beginning for a concrete dual basis, isn't it ?

Unfortunately there is no such simple candidate for the third element.

Indee, with $ev_2$, we have :

$$ev_2(p_1)=-1, \ \ ev_2(p_2)=2,  \ \ ev_2(p_3)=2.$$

$ev_2$ is not a good candidate by itself, but it suffices to aggregate it with the other ones in the following way :

$$e:=ev_0-2ev_1+\frac12 ev_2 \ \ \text{to get}$$

$$e(p_1)=0, \ \ e(p_2)=0,  \ \ e(p_3)=1.$$

> > Therefore $\{ev_0,ev_1,e\}$ constitute a dual basis of the initial one.

Comment: No comment on any of the 3 solutions that have been given ?